# Modify a script loaded via jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to add an `id` to the `<script>` tag of a script that is loaded via `jQuery.ajax();`?

Here is how I load the script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'js/script.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function() {

        // do something
    }
});
```

I would need that to be able to identify that script for future interactions.

I know I could *probably* use `dataType: 'text'`, then add the content within my own `<script></script>` tags with an `id`, and add it myself to the DOM... but if I can avoid that, I'd be happy :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once the script is loaded and running, futur modification of the textual content (or removing it from the DOM) will not affect the script. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not sure I get that right. What I'd like to do is to reload that same script later on (same functions, etc.) but the JS itself is modified in between by some server-side script. Basically I was thinking of removing it from the DOM before adding it again.

Comment: If anyone can confirm... Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this technique, the script is not added to the DOM. Instead, the returned JavaScript is evaluated as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) says:

> dataType "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

Once evaluated, the functions and variables from the lazy-loaded script will remain available to the browser. Therefore, the only way to *clean-up* the code is to **delete** the function(s) from the window scope:

```
delete window.myFunctionName;
```

Once done, calling the function or trying to access any of the variables defined within it will return:

> ReferenceError: myFunctionName is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: variableName is not defined